# Windows 7 Enterprise, Service Pack 1. Software MS Office Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

In Excel I understand there is no mechanism to customise & re-label the Rows & Columns (i.e. Renaming Col. A to some text like "Item Number" and so on.
My question is regarding if it's possible to start Row Numbering at zero, or to determine a pre-allocated number of rows which contain my Headers, and then the first Row with the detail is infact seen as Row 1?
Reason for question is I work multiple INternational Projects and we use Excel to trsack alot of activities & issues. Oddly, many people will refer to, for example "Point 7"... Some people mean the ID 7 (which I have the first Column dedicated to ID Number), some mean Excel Row 7, which infact could be really ID 3, or 4 from Col. A.... Any easy way or workaround to just use the Excel Row Numbers but select from when Row 1 is counted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to change how the row or column numbers work, AFAIK.

One workaround could be to hide the rows/column numbers from view*, and implement your own in row 1 and column A, formatted in a way that mimics the row/column headers.

The downside here is that you lose the functionality of clicking a row number to select a whole row - but you've always got <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> :)

**EDIT**: To hide row/column headers, click `File > Options > Advanced` then scroll down to the `Display options for this worksheet` section and untick `Show row and column headers`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, this is pretty much the way I was thinking to go without knowing if there were more possiblities or Add-Ins... (anecditedly, purely by chance a colleague of mine was exporting files as CSV's from a database, and somewhow, when we opened one of them in Excel, the Excel Row & Columns were infact totally relabelled with Wingdings font characters... so, seems possible, but probably not a standard feature :-))... they did this by accident